# How To Extract Name in this HTML Element using rvest

Tags: html, r

I've searched through many rvest scraping posts but can't find an example like mine. I'm following the R vignette example (https://blog.rstudio.com/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/) for selectorgadget, but inputting my use case as necessary. None of selector gadget's suggestions get me what I need. I need to extract the name for each review on the page. A sample of what the name looks like under the hood is as follows:

`<span itemprop="name" class="sg_selected">This Name</span>`

Here's my code to this point. Ideally, this code should get me the individual names on this web page.

```
    library(rvest)
    library(dplyr)

    dsa_reviews <- 
    read_html("https://www.directsalesaid.com/companies/traveling-
    vineyard#reviews")

    review_names <- html_nodes(dsa_reviews,'#reviews span')

    df <- bind_rows(lapply(xml_attrs(review_names), function(x) 
    data.frame(as.list(x), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)))
```

Apologies if this is a duplicate question or if it's not formatted correctly. Please feel free to request any necessary edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is :

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

dsa_reviews <- 
  read_html("https://www.directsalesaid.com/companies/traveling-vineyard#reviews")

html_nodes(dsa_reviews,'[itemprop=name]') %>% 
  html_text() 

 [1] "Traveling Vineyard"     ""                      
 [3] "Kiersten Ray-kuhn"      "Miley Sama"            
 [5] " Nancy Shawtone "       "Amanda Moore"          
 [7] "Matt"                   "Kathy Barzal"          
 [9] "Lesa Brinker"           "Lori Stryker"          
[11] "Jeanette Holtman"       "Penny Notarnicola"     
[13] "Laura Ann"              "Nicole Lafave"         
[15] "Gretchen Hess Miller"   "Gina Devine"           
[17] "Ashley Lawton Converse" "Morgan Williams"       
[19] "Angela Baston Mckeone"  "Traci Feshler"         
[21] "Kisha Marshall Dlugos"  "Jody Cole Dvorak"
```

Colin

Comment: This is great, thank you! Do you also know how to also extract the datepublished? I tried to use the same format, but the date I need is set to a tag called content next to itemprop=datePublished.

Comment: try `html_nodes(dsa_reviews,'.text-muted') %>% html_text()` for the date only, `html_nodes(dsa_reviews,'.review__name.h4') %>% 
  html_text() %>%
  gsub("\n", " ", .) %>%
  as_tibble()` for the name + the date.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. This gives me the date in relation to now (1 week ago, etc). Is there any way that you know of to grab the actual date which lives in the same class, but under the name content? If not, no worries, but that would be ideal!

Comment: `reviewers <- html_nodes(dsa_reviews,'[itemprop=author]') %>% html_text() %>% gsub("[\n]*", "", .) ; date <- html_nodes(dsa_reviews,'[itemprop=datePublished]') %>% html_attr(name = "content") ; data.frame(reviewers, date)`

Comment: Did you just learn this by trial and error or is there a reference guide somewhere that talks about how to format different tag/class/etc types?